PowerPoint Crashes Tried Everything I know
I have been living with a crashing powerpoint for a long time (Over a year). I'm a midlevel computer tech. Hardware and software.
What happens: Upon starting PowerPoint it ether crashes before it opens or within a minute after it starts. Upon restarting PowerPoint I'm prompted to start in safe mode which I do and there is no crash. I close PowerPoint and open it again and it crashes. repeat with safe mode.This is the cycle.
What I have done to try and solve this but didn't work:
Disabled all add-in's in PowerPoint.
Disabled anti-virus/malware/firewall applications.
Uninstalled all add-in's application and anti-virus software from the computer.
Performed a MS Office 365 repair short and long.
Removed MS Office 365, reboot and reinstall.
Used CCleaner on temp files and registry.
Deleted files in %temp% folder that CCleaner did not.
Run virus and malware scans with Vipre Internet security and MalwareBytes.(Note! I do not run two AV programs on my computer at the same time. Vipre is my primary AV security application.)
Upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11.
Run the scannow option to ensure that there are no corrupted windows files.
Updated MotherBoard BIOS.
What has worked:
I created a new Windows profile and installed MS Office 365. PowerPoint works fine even with the three third party Add-ins installed and active.
PowerPoint works fine but with this profile however because it's on the same computer I cannot easily access my files on OneDrive because my original profile login is associated with my MS account.
Help that I'm looking for:
I'm looking for a solution that does not involve a clean install of Windows.
I recently leaned about the Process Monitor and wondered if that could help solve this.
PowerPnt.exe showed some Results as: "names not found, buffer overruns or too small, file locked with only readers, no such file and reparse" I'm not certian but from what I could tell these should not cause a crash.
I'm looking for guidance on how to isolate what is different between the two windows profiles so I can find what causing this crash and resolve it on my primary Windows profile.
System information:
Windows 11 pro, Intel i9, 64GB RAM,Two 2TB M.2 SSD, One SATA SSD 1TB, 3 external USB HDD, Two 24" Monitors at 1920x1080 59 Hz.(one is a touch screen), Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti display card, MotherBoard is ASUS Z490-A BIOS 2801 (10/27/2023).

What does Event Viewer say? Replacing profiles isn't all that difficult. If there is something wrong with your profile (which is what you've narrowed this down to), sometimes the only and correct course of action is to blow the profile away and recreate it. Using OneDrive makes this pretty easy for most users, though you'll want to look through any apps that don't have their configs backed up in OneDrive folders and export their configs prior to deleting the broken profile.

As @music2myear states, you know there is an issue with your Windows profile. To make PowerPoint work, you'll need to create a new profile, as you've done, and then move all your work and applications to that profile. However, you might want to try a workaround using another application, such as free LibreOffice's Impress, which works like PowerPoint, until you go through the whole procedure of moving everything to the new profile, on- and offline.

What I don't know how to do is move my MS login to the new profile.  It won't let me until I disassociate my primary profile from my MS login.  It's not the moving of all my files because OneDrive does that.  I do have local files and I'm not sure all my applications will function in the new profile. they all need to be tested. Other presentation software is not an option because I have an add-in that I need and it's not designed to work with other presentation applications. I'm hoping someone know how to debug this.

Is there some reason why the needed add-in you mention could not be installed into the new profile?

The add-in is installed in the new profile and it works great. I mentioned about the add-in because music2myear suggested that I try using LibreOffice instead of PowerPoint. The add-in won't work with other office suites or presentation software. It's only designed to work with PowerPoint.

OK, I see. Another thought: since you mention that safe mode works, check to see if there are updates for your video driver. PowerPoint queries the driver so see if it can perform Operation X. If the driver says "Yes", PowerPoint hands the op off to the driver. If the driver is mistaken/lying, it can cause crashes. In Safe mode, PPT doesn't ask the driver, it just uses its own internal (slower but safer) routines instead of relying on the driver.
